# I have 3 different algorithms for a specific number and I don't know how to make them work properly

Tags: java

I am taking a Java course and they give us a project to make. I am struggling with some requirements and I am trying to understand them.

> findTreause (int treasureCode): the method will update the player's status according to the treasure found, as follows:
>
> if treasureCode is the perfect number:
> score increases by 5000 points
> lives increases by 1 life
> health becomes 100.
>
> if treasureCode is a prime number:
> score increases by 1000 points
> lives increases by 2 lives
> health increases by 25, but cannot exceed 100
>
> if treasureCode is an even number and the sum of its digits is divisible by 3 then that object is a trap. Therefore, the player's situation changes as follows:
> score decreases by 3000 points
> health decreases by 25.
>
> if health reaches 0, then lives will be decremented by 1 and health reset to 100 any other numbers do not show "magic powers", therefore the only status update is:
> score will be incremented by treasureCode
>
> Note: the previous criteria will be tested one by one (i.e. in the given order) and the status will be updated according to the first validated condition. For example: if one treasureCode is both a "perfect number" and an "even number with the sum of digits divisible by 3", the status will be updated according to "perfect number" because this criterion precedes the other.

I've made the perfect and prime number algorithms, but for example when I enter number 6 which is a perfect number, it increases for prime number too.

```java
package game;

public class PlayerStatus {
    
    public void findArtifact(int artifactCode) {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < artifactCode; i++) {
            if (artifactCode % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        if (sum == artifactCode) {
            this.score += 5000;
            this.lives += 1;
            this.health = 100;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < artifactCode / 2; i++) {
            if (artifactCode % i == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        this.score += 1000;
        this.lives += 2;
        this.health += 25;
     }

package game;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PlayerStatus player1 = new PlayerStatus();
        player1.findArtifact(6);
        System.out.println(player1.getScore());
        System.out.println(player1.getLives());
        System.out.println(player1.getHealth());
```

This is the output:

- 6000
- 3
- 125

I know it's easy, but I have a mental breakdown. Can someone explain what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have each condition in a separate **if**?
If you do, it will evaluate every condition by separate, and will change your character stats. In order to do what you want, you have to next conditions like this:

```
if(perfect) {
  do somehting;
} else if(prime) {
  do something;
} else if(even and sum of digits...) {
  do something;
} else {
  do something if nothing matches criteria;
}
```

Comment: i've tried to put them in a else but how can i rewrite the code for 'else if' if i have a 'for'.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve my problem:

```
public static boolean isPerfect(int artifactCode) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= artifactCode / 2; i++) {
            if (artifactCode % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        if (sum == artifactCode) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int artifactCode) {

        for (int i = 2; i <= artifactCode / 2; i++) {
            if (artifactCode % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean sumOfDigits(int artifactCode) {
        int sum = 0;
        int lastDigit = 0;
        while (artifactCode > 0) {
            lastDigit = artifactCode % 10;
            sum = sum + lastDigit;
            artifactCode /= 10;
        }
        if (sum % 3 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void findArtifact(int artifactCode) {
        if (isPerfect(artifactCode)){
            this.score += 5000;
            this.lives += 1;
            this.health = 100;
        } else if (isPrime(artifactCode)) {
            this.score += 1000;
            this.lives += 2;
            this.health += 25;
        } else if (sumOfDigits(artifactCode) && artifactCode % 2 == 0) {
            this.score -= 3000;
            this.health -= 25;
        } else {
            this.score = artifactCode;
        }

    }
```